# How to behaviour test a Component which uses React Bootstrap with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-bootstrap

In pseudo code:

```
MyComponent: React.createClass
doThis: () ->
  //do something
render: () ->

  <div>
    <button className='something' onClick={clickHandler()}>click this button</button>
    <ReactBootstrap.Pagination onSelect=(this.doThis) items=3 />
  </div> 

//tests

component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument <MyComponent>

//test1

el = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass component, 'something'
TestUtils.Simulate.click el

//test2
el = TestUtils.srcyRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag component, 'li'
TestUtils.Simulate.click el[0]
```

In test1 the click is fired. In test2 doThis() is not called

In both cases I definitely have a dom node and am firing the click on it. onSelect is the correct prop to use to pass to ReactBoostrap.Pagination. It works fine in the browser.

The Pagination class in Bootstrap uses onClick and seems to attach it to the li element it renders so I think I am targeting the correct element. (Edit: looking at Bootstrap-react's test for the Pagination component that targets the a tag which is rendered inside the li https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/test/PaginationSpec.js. However; I tried that too so I don't think that is my problem).

It seems to be to do with trying to target a dom node rendered by a child component. But I have no idea how to proceed. (Edit: or perhaps it is specific to react-bootstrap? Maybe I need to not mock some dependency...?)

Answer (score 0):

The answer, for me, was to not mock 'classnames' - which is a dependency of react-bootstrap:

```
jest.dontMock 'classnames'
```

The answer was given by: http://racingtadpole.com/blog/test-react-with-jest/ so thanks to racingtadpole.